# Selecting rows by a list of values without using several ands

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `(a,b,c)`.
I have a list of values `(x,y,z)`
How can I select the rows containing exactly this three values, something like:

```
df = df[df[(a,b,c)] == (x,y,z)]
```

I know that

```
df = df[(df[a] == x) & (df[b] == y) & (df[c] == z)]
```

should work, but I'm looking for something more convenient. Does it exist ?

Comment: You could wrap that statement in a function like: `get_ind = lambda df, a, b, c, x, y, z: (df[a] == x) & (df[b] == y) & (df[c] == z)`. Then you could use that as `df = df[get_ind(df, x, y, z, a, b, c)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution using Indexing

I would set the columns as the index and use the `.loc` function

Indexing like this is the fastest way of accessing rows, while masking is very slow on larger datasets.

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                           'b':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                           'c':['z','x','y','v','u'],
                           'othervalue':range(100, 105)})

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   a  b  c  othervalue
0  1  a  z         100
1  2  b  x         101
2  3  c  y         102
3  4  d  v         103
4  5  e  u         104

In [6]: df.set_index(['a','b','c'], inplace=True)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
       othervalue
a b c            
1 a z         100
2 b x         101
3 c y         102
4 d v         103
5 e u         104

In [8]: df.loc[[4,'d','v']]
Out[8]: 
       othervalue
a b c            
4 d v         103
```

#### Extra bonus

Also, if you just want to access a certain value of a certain column, you can extend the `.loc` function to access that certain column for you, like this:

```
In [9]: df.loc[[4,'d','v'], 'othervalue']
Out[9]: 
a  b  c
4  d  v    103
Name: othervalue, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This looks sexy but I have a `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (1), lexsort depth (0)'`
I'm trying to figure it out on the interwebs but no success so far...

Comment: @nicoco Are you getting this error with my example or when integrating this into your own code? If the latter, please open a new question where you show more of your code.

Comment: I'm getting it with my code. I posted my detailed problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749675/selecting-rows-that-contain-the-max-value-of-a-variable-after-grouping-them). I could `set_index` with the `falseparams` list, but couldn't use `df.loc` with `falseparamssets[0]` without getting this error. Anyway what I've done is way too dirty, I need help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for matching the tuple `(x,y,z)` values no matter the order in the columns (just in the same row), maybe I would use [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) as:

```
df = df[df[['a','b','c']].isin([x,y,z])].dropna()
```

It would be nice comparing the timing with your boolean mask on a big dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

```
df = [df['a'],df['b'],df['c']] == [x,y,z]
```

Hope it will helpful

Comment: This is incorrect, you're creating a list of Series and comparing against a list of scalar values